# spring security - combining http basic and formlogin

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I have written following class to configure `httpBasic` and `formLogin`. However, `formLogin` authentication is not applied for the urls mentioned. `HTTPBasic` authentication works for the urls mentioned. kindly help to understand what is going wrong here

```
import com.sun.research.ws.wadl.HTTPMethods;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher;



@EnableWebSecurity
public class SpringSecurityConfig{

    /**
    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationEntryPoint authEntryPoint;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        //http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
        //        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        //        .and().httpBasic()
        //        .authenticationEntryPoint(authEntryPoint);
        http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,"/pay").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,"/success").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,"/cancel").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,"/create-payment").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,"/execute-payment").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,"/api/ipad/sendSMS").hasRole("USER")
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,"/api/ipad/deactivate").hasRole("USER")
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,"/**").hasRole("USER")
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,"/**").hasRole("USER")
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.PUT,"/**").hasRole("USER")
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE,"/**").hasRole("USER")
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.PATCH,"/**").hasRole("USER")
                .and().httpBasic()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(authEntryPoint);
    }
    **/
    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("admin").password("123abc").roles("USER");
    }


    @Configuration
    @Order(1)
    public static class ApiWebSecurityConfigurationAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {



        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,"/pay").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,"/success").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,"/cancel").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,"/create-payment").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,"/execute-payment").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,"/api/ipad/sendSMS").hasRole("USER")
                    .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,"/api/ipad/deactivate").hasRole("USER")
                    .and().httpBasic();
                    //.authenticationEntryPoint(authEntryPoint);
        }
    }

//    @Configuration
//    public static class FormLoginWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
//
//        @Override
//        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
//            http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
//                    .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,"/**").hasRole("USER")
//                    .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,"/**").hasRole("USER")
//                    .antMatchers(HttpMethod.PUT,"/**").hasRole("USER")
//                    .antMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE,"/**").hasRole("USER")
//                    .antMatchers(HttpMethod.PATCH,"/**").hasRole("USER")
//                    .and().formLogin();
////            http
////                    .authorizeRequests()
////                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
////                    .and()
////                    .formLogin();
//
//        }
//    }
    @Configuration
    public static class FormLoginWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
//            http
//                    .authorizeRequests()
//                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
//                    .and()
//                    .formLogin();
                        http.authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,"/**").hasRole("USER")
                    .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,"/**").hasRole("USER")
                    .antMatchers(HttpMethod.PUT,"/**").hasRole("USER")
                    .antMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE,"/**").hasRole("USER")
                    .antMatchers(HttpMethod.PATCH,"/**").hasRole("USER")
                    .and().formLogin();
        }
    }


}
```

basically, what I am doing in above configuration is that, if user is accessing any page other than what is mentioned in `order(1)` , I want the application to use form based authentication. However, authentication only works for `order(1)` pages, for rest it does not apply authentication. Kindly help to understand if I my configuration is not proper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to combine the "formlogin" authentication and the "http basic" authentication (used for the rest api) within the same configure() method?

Maybe it will help, and even shorten the code.

Example:

```
  @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
    .formLogin()
    .loginPage("/login")
    .and()
    .httpBasic()
    .realmName("Spittr")
    .and()
    ...
    }
```

"Notice that the and() method is used to chain together different configuration directives in configure()."

(via Spring in Action 4th edition, page 269)